# Theory on a major chord in the song Vincent

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

In the song Vincent (Starry, Starry Night), in the chorus when the lyrics go "...set them free. They would not listen, they did not know how. Perhaps they'll listen now", the chords are (as far as I know) Em, A, Am, D, G. The song is in G major, so the A major is out of the key. Is there some theory on why the A major works in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to understand this chord progression is by not seeing the Am as a resolution. Some tension-and-release patterns last much longer than 2 bars.

In this case `Em-Am-D-G` would be a normal progression resolving to `G`. With the added `A` chord, extra tension is built, and although some of that tension is relieved with the Am chord, the progression's true resolution is still at the `G` chord.

Comment: Good call ?!.......

Comment: Great straightforward answer. Now i won't have to write one myself.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for theory. Use of V/V is commonplace - here in G, the V is D, and the V of that is A.

Another way it gets explained is the use of a *parallel* key. Here, a little contrived, but taking the *relative* minor of G, Em. Make this into the parallel key of E *major*, and one of the most prominent chords in that key is its IV of A major.

Theory, as oft said here only tries to explain what's happening - it cannot and will not dictate what must happen, and I guess that most if not all of non-diatonic stuff could eventually be explained away - we like to do exercises such as those!

Comment: Ok right, but usually the V/V would act as a secondary dominant, but here it resolves to Am. I haven't seen the V/V used like this anywhere else. One other interpretation came to mind: The C# of A major would be a #4 in the key of G, so could this be a modal interchange from G lydian? Makes sense?

Comment: Just about any way of looking at it, with regard to it making sense, will do! Modal interchange is another way of doing that.

Comment: I think the best way to understand this chord progression is by *not* seeing the Am as a resolution. Some tension-and-release patterns last much longer than 2 bars. In this case Em-Am-D-G would be a normal progression resolving to G. With the added A chord, extra tension is built, and although some of that tension is relieved with the Am chord, the progression's true resolution is still at the G chord.

Comment: @LeeWhite: Now that is an explanation I like. Thank you.

Comment: @LeeWhite - change that comment into an answer.

Comment: @Tim - Done! :-)

Comment: I think it's best to also leave to comment here so the context with the previous discussion is retained.

Answer (score 1):

In (CPP) music theory, the ii-V-I sequence often occurs with the ii replaced by a II or a II7 or a ii6 (and the V can become a V7). I'm guessing that similar modifications occur in pop music. Mostly it's done for variety.

Answer (score 1):

It works because it sounds good.  You've been offered several ways of labelling it.   Music is FULL of 'out of key' chords.  Adjust your mind-set to see them as normal.

Comment: Sure. What I'm looking for is some general pattern, as in, "in this type of music they often use X to get effect Y". If there is a label for something, it's easier for me to remember and apply in new contexts. From the answers I've got, it seems there is no clear label for this chord. So the answer seems to be that it just a special chord for a little variety.